# Function with setinterval is executed without being called in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

I have the following function that is supposed to scroll down page only when a button is clicked

```
function scrollToHome(){
    if (window.innerHeight = 123){
        for(i=0; i<=123; i++){
            window.scrollBy(0, i);
        }
    }
}
var myInterval = setInterval (scrollToHome, 1000);
homeButton.addEventListener("click", myInterval);
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

The thing is that upon saving the code, the function starts executing by itself infinitely.

Comment: `setInterval (scrollToHome, 1000)` already starts the interval. You want to bind a function that creates the interval on the button click, not the result of the `setInterval` call.

Comment: it should be `var myInterval = () => setInterval (scrollToHome, 1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your interval in a function.

```
var myInterval = null;

function scrollToHome(){
    if (window.innerHeight = 123){
        for(i=0; i<=123; i++){
            window.scrollBy(0, i);
        }
    }
    if (condition && myInterval) clearInterval(myInterval);
}

homeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
     myInterval = setInterval(scrollToHome, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I doubt that the clearing of the interval should be where it is, but this generally goes in the right direction.

Comment: This will not cancel the intervals that are created while the condition is false.

Comment: @deceze Edited. Better ?